# Array for li element

Tags: javascript

I just finished learning Javascript. Now i am doing some practical test to further sharpen my knowledge. I look for some random practical projects online and i found this site (https://skillcrush.com/2018/06/18/projects-you-can-do-with-javascript/) 9. Build a JavaScript To-Do List.

As i scan the codes, i understand how the flow works but got confused in this particular section:

*Everytime the createListElement() function is triggered, does it create an array of li element?

*How does the delete button created for every 'li' is only associated to work with that specific li element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createListElement()` function creates a **single** list element. Here is what it does.

- Creates the element.
- Adds it to the list.
- Adds the strike-through.
- Adds the delete button.

The delete button is a **child element** of the list item. In it's onclick listener, it stores the specific `li` element that it belongs to. Perhaps more ideal code in that area would look something like this:

```js
function deleteListItem(e) {
    e.path[0].parentElement.classList.add("delete")
}

dBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem)
```

In all onclick events, `e.path[0]` is the element that was clicked. Since the delete button has no children within it that will also trigger that function, it will always be the delete button. Then, by getting the parent element, it will always be the right list item.

Comment: There you go! the key word "Parent-child" relationship is the answer. I just finished some video tutorials for JavaScript. I was expecting for some loops and index numbers to make this work hehehe. This one is a pretty clever solution. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Just be careful, this is a bit more complicated if the equivalent of the delete button also has children.

Comment: whoaaa!!! i'll get back to the drawing board  and get a deeper dive on this topic hehehe. there's so much more to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is related code:

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li"); // creates an element "li"
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //makes text from input field the li text
    ul.appendChild(li); //adds li to ul
    input.value = ""; //Reset text input 
    //START STRIKETHROUGH
    // because it's in the function, it only adds it for new items
    function crossOut() {
        li.classList.toggle("done");
    }
    li.addEventListener("click",crossOut);
    //END STRIKETHROUGH
    // START ADD DELETE BUTTON
    var dBtn = document.createElement("button");
    dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    li.appendChild(dBtn);
    dBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);
    // END ADD DELETE BUTTON
    //ADD CLASS DELETE (DISPLAY: NONE)
    function deleteListItem(){
        li.classList.add("delete")
    }
    //END ADD CLASS DELETE
}
```

A1: While `createListElement` triggered, `var li = document.createElement("li")` would create a single `li` element, and append to DOM by `ul.appendChild(li)`

A2: `var dBtn = document.createElement("button");` create a button element and append to `li` element by `li.appendChild(dBtn)`.

`dBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);` add a click event to the corresponding button, if button clicked, it would trigger defined `deleteListItem` function. And in `deleteListItem` function:

```
function deleteListItem(){
    li.classList.add("delete")
}
```

`li` refers to the 'li' element you just created. Thus it would add a `delete` class to associated `li` element and hide `li`.

Comment: There you go! the key word "Parent-child" relationship is the answer. I just finished some video tutorials for JavaScript. I was expecting for some loops and index numbers to make this work hehehe. This one is a pretty clever solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *Everytime the createListElement() function is triggered, does it create an array of li element?

Close! Think of *ul* as the parent container of all the *li* items. In this specific example there is *ul* already defined globally:

```
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
```

Everytime createListElemet() is triggered it creates a new *li* element and appends to the existing *ul* container.

> How does the delete button created for every 'li' is only associated
>   to work with that specific li element?

If you follow the code line at a time -

```
var dBtn = document.createElement("button");    //create button element
dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X")); //create text node with text "X" and append to the button element
li.appendChild(dBtn);                           //append the deleteBtn + text node to the li element. Here is why that specific delete element is associated to that *li* element.
```

Comment: Now this comment in the code make sense!  I just finished some video tutorials for JavaScript. I was expecting for some loops and index numbers to make this work hehehe.